# Curious badge strangely not awarded yet (in meta)

Tags: support, badges

Why is the curious badge still there? It has been for days, and it says 5/5.

[image]

Update: it seems I do have 5 upvoted questions in meta

[image]

**PS: I'm not desperate for badges (at least not in meta). But this is kind of annoying.** (first world problem, I know)

Comment: I've had the same thing, except on the main site.  Eventually, it was awarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get upvotes on the questions.

> Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a
>   **positive question record**

Comment: Agreed. But then the system should not count 5/5, if these questions have not yet qualified for it. It is like counting all your questions as Socratic, even though they have not yet become Socratic. And it seems that I actually have upvoted questions. See edited question.

Comment: @luchonacho Note that only 5 out of 11 questions asked here on Meta by you have had upvotes done to them.  Three have a good number of downvotes, one is deleted, and two have no votes at all.  If the one deleted doesn't count, then you have an even split between 'positive' and 'neutral and negative' - the split is why it's not a "positive question record", as I understand the system.

Comment: @ThomasWard Oh, I see. That makes more sense. Cheers

Comment: Awarded now. :)